# Error 403 ONLY for Ubuntu clients

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server

I'm facing a very strange situation:
if I try to reach the gescom.it site (which I have accessed for years up to now) from a laptop with ubuntu 22.04 or from a pc with ubuntu 20.04 the returned page is

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.gescom.it Port 80
```

Same bad result accessing from chrome or firefox.
If I check the "padlock" on the address bar, the SSL certificate shows that the site is the correct one.

I add that the site is visible if I try to connect in "terminal" mode with lynx.

If with the same machines I restart in dual boot with Windows, the page served is the normal one, and navigation continues correctly; this makes me think that the corporate router has nothing to do with the problem.
As proof, if I connect the laptop to another router with another internet line, the situation does not change.

I contacted my provider, who said the problem was not with him.
Yet the 403 error seems to be a permissions problem, which strangely only occurs with ubuntu clients... what could it depend on?

Does it depend on a web server configuration or ubuntu parameters?

The strange thing is that the problem has never arisen until today...

Does the site look normal to you?

Have you ever encountered a similar problem?

Comment: I removed the name of your provider as they appear to be unhappy about being named in association with this, and are not the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to reproduce the problem, deduced the cause and provide a workaround.

I have come across this kind of thing before (a long time ago, and less blatantly).

The issue is with web server configuration, and its almost certainly deliberate.  Maybe they have been dealing with a DoS attack or similar and a heuristic picked up on the browser string and blocked it.   As relatively few people use Linux on their desktop I guess they thought the reduction in traffic was worth it.

Its a really dumb thing to do as it causes a lot of false positives, and is easy to work around.

One way to work around this is to install a plugin in your browser to modify the browser string sent.  I use Firefox and installed User-Agent Switcher and Manager extension.  When I set this to pretend to be Chrome for Windows, the site came up for me.   I assume there are similar plugins for Chrome.

Comment: This is correct. I've tested that by altering the browser user-agent the site gescom.it will permit access as well.

Comment: @Giulano69 The problem is not with "the ISP" - I've requested your comment referencing them by name be deleted (can't be edited) as they are clearly frustrated/upset/trying to engage in reputation management on this, and they are not the cause of the issue. (the issue is with the website provider)